# my android registeration class

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

hi i am beginner at android and in programming at all, 
so i copy and tried to understand the following code from this link [my brin back](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13193/android-mysql-php-json-part-5-developing-the-android-application/) so evry thing is worked except  registration.
the problem is when iam running my app on my device; it returns the same message as invalid username in all situations i do not know the reson

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText user, pass;
private Button  mRegister;

 // Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script


private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/webservice/login.php";



//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                 /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                boolean failure = false;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    String username = user.getText().toString();
                    String password = pass.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");

                        //Posting user data to script
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                               LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                    // full json response
                        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                        // json success element
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                        finish();
                            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    return null;

                }
                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    if (file_url != null){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

so any one can help me please ...

Comment: please tell clearly what is error?

Comment: the error happened when i test the app at registration operation like when i tried to register a user whith a new user name and new password then the app display a toast message tell me like this user name is already exist even if it not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write  getting success code on postExecute(), i.e.

                 class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                 /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                boolean failure = false;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    String username = user.getText().toString();
                    String password = pass.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");

                        //Posting user data to script
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                               LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    return null;

                }
                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                    pDialog.dismiss();

// full json response
                        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                        // json success element
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                        finish();
                            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        }

                    if (file_url != null){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
```